# Возможно ли убрать всплывающею информацию о группе, и оставить только ссылку?

Tags: python, aiogram

[image: Подскажите возможно убрать всплывающею информацию о группе, и о]

Подскажите возможно убрать всплывающею информацию о группе, и оставить только тест с подсвечивающим VK для перехода по ссылке?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Объясните конкретнее, что вас интересует, приведите ваш код. В текущем виде непонятно, о чем вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте параметр `disable_web_page_preview = True` в функции отправки сообщения.

Например, так:

```
await bot.send_message(chat_id=123, text="Тыкай сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1544922/Возможно-ли-убрать-всплывающею-информацию-о-группе-и-оставить-только-ссылку/1544927#1544927", disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

---

Подробнее: [тык](https://aiogram-birdi7.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram/types/message.html)

Comment: Спасибо работает!)

Comment: Не за что, обращайтесь:)